# How to transfer data between two Windows personal computers?

Tags: networking, security, performance, file-transfer

I have two Windows 11 desktop computers that are next to each other about two meters apart.

I want to transfer files between them in the form of copy and paste, for example copy-paste files from computer A to computer B or from computer B to computer A.

The files I want to transfer ranges from a few kilobytes to more than a gigabyte.

I want to do this without a USB flash drive but also without any cloud software.

Is there a way for this? Is there perhaps a **cable** that I could buy and use it when both computers are working?

I would greatly desire to avoid any kind of configuration of anything (for example, I never configured a Local Area Network and I don't think I want to learn how to do that, at least not at this point), I just seek a simple method for file transfer.

Comment: Are the computers on a network (say both connected to a Modem that includes a router)?  Connect by mapping folders.  Make sure Network discovery and file/print sharing are enabled on both computers.

Comment: Lots of possibilities, starting from something like USB transfer cable, ending at various local network solutions.

Comment: If you have a fast local network, that's the simplest solution.

Comment: The computers are not on the same network and I greatly desire to avoid configuring a LAN network if I can.

Comment: Please review edited question.

Comment: The files I want to transfer ranges from a few kilobytes to more than a gigabyte.  ..... You want to be sure any USB solution is USB 3 or speed will be an issue. I strongly suggest you get a friend or contractor to set up a proper LAN. Best over time.

Answer (score 0):

If your devices are on separate networks, as you mentioned, then I would recommend using a [USB data transfer/link cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20data%20transfer%20cable). Keep in mind they are not compatible with all systems though, but they should work between 2 Windows devices without any problem, check the supported OSes to confirm Windows 11 support when buying one.

Why is it OS-specific? Because while USB is a universal standard, sending files between 2 computers with it is not. You can't do it with a regular cable because USB is supposed to work in a master-slave way. In this case you're trying to connect 2 masters. So you need a special cable and that special cable needs to set the proper device (usually a part in the middle) as slave and manage bidirectional communication, which may require a driver, whether plug & play or some cables even may require specific software

Comment: What did you mean by `check the supported OSes to confirm Windows 11 support when buying one.`? I would doubt that manufacturers would sell such a cable dedicated only for Linux, for example. Or have you meant only for **Apple** for example?

Comment: What? That's exactly what I wrote, that they are dedicated for various systems. They're not standard USB cables and require additional drivers.

Comment: I am surprised to learn that there might be a USB cable for Windows and a USB cable for **Apple**, because I thought USB is a universal standard...

Comment: USB is a universal standard indeed, but sending files between 2 computers with it is **not**. You can't do it with a regular cable because USB is supposed to work in a master-slave way. In this case you're trying to connect 2 masters. So you need a special cable and that special cable needs to set the proper device as slave, which may require a driver, whether plug & play or some even may require specific software.

Comment: @somo Apparently, there's such a thing "Plugable USB 2.0 Transfer Cable"

Comment: @Destroy666 I don't think this'll work; Also, I hate buying stuff when I can already do with existing hardware. He has a network; That'll suffice.

Comment: @Netan I have thought about that and I have tried USB Disk on Keys; it was darn slow for even 100mb and I am afraid a cable would be slow too... But it may be worth a try.

Comment: @somo I don't know exactly, but I'm guessing your using 'b' as bits, not Bytes. If so - A regular network interface can copy at 100Mb or 1Gb, it depends on the computer. Even the 100Mb will be than what you are using today, since you only copy the files ONCE, not twice.

Comment: To clarify - a single Byte consists of 8 bits. That's how everything in computers is being built and designed. Meaning that 100Mb is about 12.5MB, or 1000Mb ( aka 1Gb ) is equal to 125MB ( given you're using SSD or a high-performance HDD that can WRITE at that speed ).

Comment: Why wouldn't it work...? And they wrote they don't want a network solution.

Comment: @Netan I don't think what you wrote is related to what I wrote. I assume you didn't understand me.

Answer (score -1):

Windows has a built-in method for file sharing. It is a bit technical but it will work the best, and won't require installation of any software.

You can share for "everyone" or just specific users on the computer - BUT **don't give them write-access**, and **don't do it on a computer that travels** outside of your house ( so, any laptop whatsorver ).

These look like great guides. Please, ask if you have any question about them.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf#:~:text=Select%20the%20Start%20button%2C%20then%20select%20Settings%20%3E%20Network%20%26%20internet,Turn%20off%20password%20protected%20sharing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20Start%20button%2C%20then%20select%20Settings%20%3E%20Network%20%26%20internet,Turn%20off%20password%20protected%20sharing).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-R44Clys9A
notes:

- the renaming is not necesary, but it will just help you to not get confused when working on them remotely

Answer (score -1):

If both PCs happen to have a spare network (RJ45) port, then the ideal solution is:

1. Use a [crossover cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00080E1M0)
2. Configure the Ethernet NICs on both PCs with static ipv4 addresses (e.g. 192.168.2.xx)

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-transfer-files-with-a-crossover-cable

Comment: you don't need static IPv4 addressing for any of that. Link-local autoconfiguration should work beautifully here, and windows share discovery definitely does.

Comment: These are the results from Google for "sharing files locally". You haven't explained how to do any of them, or how it'll help ( 1 - irrelevant, since most cables are already are; 2 - irrelevant, since static/DHCP works the same when using them correctly )

Comment: If the OP can simply log on to the same LAN as the PC he's trying to copy from: more power to him.  That's easy.  OTHERWISE: if he can't (for whatevever reason) .. and the PCs are "two meters apart" - he can easily connect the two with an Ethernet cable to copy files.  I've occasionally done so myself.  The links I cited discuss exactly how to configure a static IP.  It's simple, it's useful.

Comment: Paulsm crossover cables are a remnant from the 90s, before gigabit Ethernet became the standard on Mainboards, which mandates negotiation of cabling. So, your technical sources are twenty years behind, and you reproducing Google results that you don't really understand isn't really that useful!